# How much current does this Opto isolator output (HCPL-3180)?

Tags: opto-isolator

I wanted to use it like this in this configuration][How much current does this Opto isolator output (HCPL-3180) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How much current does this Opto isolator output (HCPL-3180) ?

The first page of the data sheet gives some strong clues that I have enhanced with red boxes: -

[image]

> I wanted to know the average current which will be fed to the MOSFET

If the MOSFET gate-source capacitance is (say) 10 nF and it gets charged to (say) 12 volts, then the peak current will be as stated above (2 to 2.5 amps) and the charge time will be decided by this formula: -

$$i = C\cdot \dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

Plugging in 12 volts for "dv" and 2 amps for "i" gives a "dt" (time) of 60 ns. This will be an approximate value because the current will be falling from 2 amps to zero amps over the charge period but something like 100 ns will be reasonable.

If you are switching the MOSFET at 1 MHz, you can make a reasonable argument that 1 amp flows for 100 ns and zero amps flows for about 900 ns repeating every 1000 ns. This approximates the average current to 100 mA.

Comment: thats the peak current , I wanted to know the average current which will be fed to the MOSFET

Comment: I have uploaded a picture of what Im trying to achieve, I wanted to know the average current which outputs by the driver so i can calculate the value of the charging and discharging resistors, using the formula Qg = Ig* t , or if i could find out the time

Comment: My amended answer should give you all the information you need. If you want a more precise answer, use a simulation tool. There are quite a few free ones available. I use micro-cap.

Comment: so if my VGS is 15V and the total input capacitance of the MOSFET is 19860pF and I am generating PWM from an Arduino with a frequency of 4kHZ how do i go about it, sorry I am student

Comment: should the time be the maximum switching speed of the HCPL3180 which is 4us ?

Comment: The 4 us appears to be related to the maximum switching frequency of 250 kHz. The rise time (the speed at which the output switches into a 10 nF in series with 10 ohm load as specified on page 7 of the data sheet) is 25 ns. I strongly suggest you simulate the circuit shown on sheet 11 (figure 23). At this point I would be using a simulator so any further discussion about rise (or fall) time should be answered by you using a sim tool.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my teacher said i should calculate it at 1us, however I am not sure why and I cannot ask him for another 3 weeks or so: Qg = Ig * t    and Q = CV --------   19860pF * 15 = 297.7nC         297.7nC / 1us = 297.7mA      than multiply by 2 for a safety factor of 100%

Comment: Well, it looks like the opto isn't specified to run at 1 us so maybe give him a few answers for different frequencies so that you cover all the eventualities.

Comment: and than from this i can calculate the Rg resistor values, but I don't know where the 1us came from,

Comment: Maybe the guy setting the question didn't look at the data sheet.

Comment: yes that could be it, so at which time shall I be calculating ? does it specify some where ?

Comment: Provide your answer with a few options. But, the bottom line is that if the arduino is producing PWM at only 4 kHz, then the avaerage current needs to be aclculated using 250 us and not 1 us or 2.5 us. You'll have to decide this - present answers that cover the possible options.

Comment: Ok thank you , could I ask you another question in regards to a 7815 Voltage regulator I am using in my H bridge ?

Comment: Raise a new question is my advice. And, [take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how to please the folk answering your questions.

Comment: I Have previously but I wanted to make sure, I have added the schematic and the problem is lets say the power sully is at 24V than the output of the 7815 regulator after a shot period of time becomes the same as what ever the inout voltage is ?

Comment: @DanielBashy please DO NOT evolve this current question the way you have by adding that new circuit diagram. Ask a proper new question for this different subject else it makes my answer look stupid and incomplete.

Comment: I have removed it but I wanted to ask you

Comment: I apologise as Im not aware of how this website works , but your answers were very useful